# Normal distribution restricted to a specific interval expression.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$, i.e. $X$ is a random variable with distribution

$$
p_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2}
$$

I haven't touched probability theory for a while it is then possible I'm mistaking something. I want to find the distribution of the conditional probability

$$
p_{X | {0 \leq X \leq \mu}}(x)
$$

to find such expression I use to CDF

$$
P_{X | 0 \leq X \leq \mu}(x)= \frac{\int_{0}^{X}p_X(x)dx}{\int_{0}^{\mu}p_X(x)dx}
$$

given that

$$
ercf(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dt \Rightarrow ercf(-x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dt \Rightarrow-ercf(-x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt
$$

and

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{x}p_X(t)dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-\left(\frac{t-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}} e^{-t^2}dt
$$

I end up with

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{x} p_X(t)dt = -\frac{1}{2}ercf\left( \frac{\mu-\sigma}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)
$$

Specifically I observe that

$$
ercf(0) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
$$

And then

$$
\int_{a}^{b} p_X(x) dx = \frac{1}{2} ercf\left(\frac{\mu-a}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right) - \frac{1}{2} ercf\left(\frac{\mu-b}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)
$$

which allows me to write

$$
P_{X | 0 \leq X \leq \mu}(x) = \frac{\frac{1}{2} ercf\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right) - \frac{1}{2} ercf\left(\frac{\mu-x}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)}
{\frac{1}{2} ercf\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right) - \frac{1}{2} ercf\left(0\right)} =
\frac{\frac{1}{2} ercf\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right) - \frac{1}{2} ercf\left(\frac{\mu-x}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)}
{\frac{1}{2} ercf\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right) - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}}
$$

I need now to differentiate and I should get (for $0 \leq x \leq \mu$)

$$p_{X | 0 \leq X \leq \mu}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \frac{e^{-\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2}}{\frac{1}{2} ercf\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\right) - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}}$$

Outside the interval I'm considering the distribution is $0$. Is all the math correct?

Comment: The détour by the CDF is really useless. In full generality, if $X$ has PDF $f_X$ and $P(a\leqslant X\leqslant b)\ne0$ then $X$ conditioned on $a\leqslant X\leqslant b$ has PDF $f_{a,b}$ with $$f_{a,b}(x)=c_{a,b}^{-1}\,f(x)\,\mathbf 1_{a\leqslant x\leqslant b}$$ and $$c_{a,b}=P(a\leqslant X\leqslant b)=\int_a^bf(t)dt$$ In your case, $X=\mu+\sigma X_0$ where $X_0$ is standard normal with CDF $\Phi$ hence $$c_{0,\mu}=P(-\mu/\sigma\leqslant X_0\leqslant0)=\tfrac12-\Phi(-\mu/\sigma)=\Phi(\mu/\sigma)-\tfrac12$$

Comment: But is my final expression correct?

Comment: The link between the CDF $\Phi$ and the error function is $$\mathrm{erf}(x)=2\Phi(x\sqrt{2})-1$$ hence $$c_{0,\mu}=\tfrac12\mathrm{erf}(\mu/(\sigma\sqrt2))$$ and surely you can translate this in terms of the *complementary* error function erfc, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: I believe this is what I'm looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Comment: Sure it is. And?

Comment: Nothing I just haven't seen that link. But I'm still wondering if my math is correct.

Comment: Sorry but cannot you connect my answer and your suggestion of formula? If one adds $$\mathrm{erfc}(x)=1-\mathrm{erf}(x)$$ to what I already explained, there is all one needs to do so...